# Creating an instance of an instance of another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to break some of my "super objects" into more manageable classes that have single (or at least limited) responsibility.

One problem I've just run into is making an object of a specific instance of a UIBarButtonItem.  In the class it is in now I first define a UIButton, and then all of the images that act as icons for that button as subviews (for instance the button represents access/control to a device, and I use the button image to show the current signal strength of that device).  Also that button is listening for NSNotifications from the device object to represent the signal strength changing, or if the device disconnects.  And pressing the button sends a message to the device to disconnect.  All of this code works perfectly fine now as a property of the RootViewController.  However, I want to pull it out into its own class as the button is shared by several classes, and it just clutters up the controller with unnecessary methods.

I tried making an separate class with an init like below.  However, this doesn't work as the self used for the button isn't the same self that is ultimately created by [UIBarButtonItem alloc] and when either the NSNotification or the button press try to send a message to the selector of "self", that object has already been dealloced.  The problem is, I'm not sure how to create a object (as defined by the class) that is just an instance of another class, as opposed to a property of an object (as it currently is for the RootViewController).

**Edit and additional explanation of my problem**

MyClass is currently subclass of UIBarButtonItem.  However, I'm not trying to use it like this: [[MyClass alloc] initWithCustomView:].  I want [MyClass alloc] init] by itself to completely create the custom view - in other words the whole point of this class is to completely contain all that is necessary for this button to create itself, manage its subviews, and take the appropriate action when it is pressed.  (I could easily make MyClass an NSObject with a public method like [MyClass setupButton] and a public property of type UIBarButtonItem.  However, I think that looks wrong because then the class is only there to create the button, but it is not the button itself.)

```
@interface MyClass : UIBarButtonItem
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        UIImage *defaultButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"...
        UIImage *defaultButtonPressed = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"....
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 30)];
        [button setBackgroundImage:defaultButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:defaultButtonPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(deviceButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //Then several UIImageViews that are added as subviews of the button, initially hidden

        //Then set up the NSNotification listener

        //Finally
        self = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    }

    return self;
}

//Then several functions to handle hiding and unhiding the subviews depending on the received device notifications, and a function to handle the button press and sending the message back to the device.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how initialization works in Cocoa. Please read ["Initialization"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Initialization.html) in the Cocoa Core Competencies guide.

Your object has already been allocated when this `init` method is run. You should not be reassigning the `self` pointer to another allocation.

Your class should first call its superclass's designated initializer `self = [super initWithWhatever:obj];`, then set up its own properties.

Comment: Thank you, I do realize this.  What I'm trying to do is figure out the correct way for MyClass to be of type UIBarButtonItem, and it to initialize it's own custom view when an instance of it is created.  Trust me, I realize how simple this question seems (which is probably why I'm missing something obvious).

Comment: Try replacing `self = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];` with `[self setCustomView:button];`

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I thought the `[super init]` might leave it in some partially initialized state, but it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to extend `UIBarButtonItem`, not create an instance of it in your `init` method. Try changing your class declaration (in your class's .h file) from this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
```

to this:

```
@interface MyClass : UIBarButtonItem
```

Then just return `self` in your `init` method. Setting `self` to a value is usually a bad idea.

If you're unsure about what's going on here, you're creating a *subclass* of UIBarButtonItem. This lets your subclass extend the superclass's functionality. If you're confused, you should take a look at subclassing/class inheritance in object-oriented languages to understand what's going on. [This guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html) documents how classes work in Objective-C.

Comment: Yes, my declaration is already for "MyClass : UIBarButtonItem".  The problem is, it's not just an extension of the UIBarButtonItem type, it's of a specific one: initWithCustomView.  This is what I'm unsure of how to do.  If I was using [[MyClass alloc] initWithCustomView:] this would be no problem.  However, I want that custom view contained within and controlled by MyClass.

Comment: @Adam If you're subclassing `UIBarButtonItem`, you can probably avoid `initWithCustomView:` altogether and move your custom view's logic into the subclass itself. But if you *really* need to use it, you can change the `if (self = [super init]) {` segment to `if (self = [super initWithCustomView:myView]) {`.

Comment: I can't test it right now.  However, there is no plain `init` for `UIBarButtonItem`.  So if I was to create an instance of MyClass, I'm unsure of what the state would be for the returned `[super init]`.  Although `UIBarButtonItem` has a property for the custom view, I have a hunch that the returned `[super init]` might be in some useless state (since it wasn't initialized with one of the five standard inits given in the class reference).  However, maybe not.  I'll test it out.

Comment: @Adam I think you misunderstood my comment, but upon further research, I think I might be able to give you a better response. *Why are you subclassing UIBarButtonItem at all?* It seems to me that if you have a custom view subclass, just use the `initWithCustomView:` method on a standard `UIBarButtonItem` instance.

Comment: I forgot to respond to you.  I want to pass around the UIBarButtonItem as simply as possible, and it's easy to set in the views with navItem.right = blah.  Currently the code is working perfectly, as I found that it was possible to init all the "buttons" and images that go into the item and then set it's own customview.